# Seeking recommendations on Gallery plugins , specifically captioning thumbnails

Tags: gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery, captions

I am looking for a gallery plugin that will display thumbnails on a page with captions beneath them, and still allow them to click through to fullsize images, preferably with a slideshow mode allowed.

I did try the NextGen plugin but despite adding the captions to my pictures they were only displayed in full size view, not on the thumbnails.

The images in use are all different source sizes and dimensions in case this makes any difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this for NextGen? - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/nextgen-image-gallery-captions

Excerpt (many other useful tips at the linked thread):

> **ENABLING CAPTIONS BELOW GALLERY IMAGES**
>   When you add a gallery to a post/page, you get this by default:
>   [nggallery id=1]
>
> You need to add this:
>   [nggallery id=1 template=caption]
>
> **GETTING THE CAPTIONS YOU JUST ENABLED TO SHOW-UP**
>
> When importing an image to a gallery, NextGEN automatically adds the
>   image filename (minus the ext) to the ALT/TITLE field of the image
>   meta data.
>
> However, the "template=caption" function is actually preset to call
>   the DESCRIPTION field of the image. If you don't have anything in the
>   DESC field, you will not see any caption (even though it is
>   technically working.)
>
> You have two options: (a) add something to the description field of
>   every image; or (b) change which field is being called.
>
> You can add a value to image DESC fields manually in NextGEN or
>   (probably) using any number of EXIF tools available.
>
> However, suppose you want the image name to automatically appear as
>   the image caption in your gallery. (Maybe you are creating a product
>   gallery where the image names are also the actual product codes, and
>   you want to display those codes below each thumbnail.) No problem -
>
> Since NG automatically creates the ALT/TITLE from the image name on
>   import, here's how to call that field:
>
> 1. In your dashboard, click Pluginns > Editor from the left-hand nav
> 2. Select plugin to edit: NextGEN Gallery
> 3. From right hand file list, click: nextgen-gallery/view/gallery-caption.php
> 4. Scroll down to this line: php echo $image->caption
> 5. Change to: php echo $image->alttext
>
> Now, your default image galleries should automatically show the
>   filename (minus ext) as the caption below every image.

Answer (score 0):

If paid products are fine too, i think http://www.tn3gallery.com/ suits you. I am using http://galleria.io/ for my projects.